# How do remove maven from eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

Maven plugin is not working perfectly,so I want to re-install in my eclipse. How do I remove Maven from eclipse?

When I am uninstalling 2 types but getting problems

1) eclipse market place--> Maven integration for eclipse luna(1.5.0)
getting msg

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
"m2e-wtp - Maven Integration for WTP" cannot be fully uninstalled because other installed software requires it.  The parts that are not required will be uninstalled.
```

and

2) Help > about eclipse > installation details > installed software

Under Eclipse ide for j2ee devlopers

There are 6 `m2e` avilable, but uninstall button is not enabled.

So how can I remove and re-install correctly?
Thanks.

Comment: Why do you think uninstalling and re-installing m2e will solve anything? Do you have any evidence to suggest that it will?

Comment: Once you mess with the bundled plugins (as opposed to the ones you install on top of the eclipse bundle), it's tough to restore the eclipse to a working point. Why not just download a new bundle and start using the new eclipse?

Comment: Just reinstall it without m2e. It usually takes much longer to fix package dependency problems.

Comment: @E-Riz...becoz pom.xml file problem.

Comment: @mystarrocks..yes.i downloaded and used new eclipse there is also same problem occured.

Comment: @eckes....how can install without m2e?becz i tried as removed m2es from plugins and features folder again i got same problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can try below appraoch

Go To Windows->Prefrences-Maven->Installations

It will show all the installed Mavens , select the one which you want to remove.

Comment: hi vikram, But there is no Maven in my Preferences List.Is any another way????????